# looping through select tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to loop through a `select` tag, with multiselect. I'm new to jQuery and I found this code, however I need to loop through all of the `option` tags, checking whether the `option` is selected or not, as I need to do something in both cases.

```
$('.multiselect').change(function () {
  $('.multiselect option:selected').each(function () {
    //do something
  });
}).trigger('change');
```

I was trying to make it into something more like this:

```
$('.multiselect').change(function () {
  $('.multiselect').each(function () {
    $('option', this).each(function() {
      if ('option':selected == true) {
        //do something
      }
      else {
        //do something else
      }
    });
  });
}).trigger('change');
```

But this doesn't work. Can someone suggest a good approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".multiselect").change(function() {
    $("option", this).each(function() {
        if(this.selected) {
             // This one is checked
        } else {
             // This one is not checked
        }
    }
});
```

Should work, I think.

Comment: Works very good! last question, i had at the end of the code .trigger('change'); But i see it works with or without it, do you know what impact it has in the code? or is it this case in particular that makes no difference?

Comment: No, I don't think it should ever make a difference... Where exactly did you put it?

Comment: If you see my initial question, is right in the end. But the change event is mentioned in the function at the beginning anyway, so it seemed a bit redundant

Comment: What it does is trigger the change with no selected boxes right at the start.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".multiselect").change(function () {    
  $(".multiselect option").each(function(){  
    if($(this).attr("selected") == "true"){  
      // do something  
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }
}
```

should work..

Comment: I get an error when doing it like this. I get Use '===' to compare with 'true'. When i make it '===' as it suggests, then it get's me all false, even when there are items selected